# Class instance calling a member function: C++ Vs Python syntax

Tags: python, c++

In a simple Python class

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
def printMsg(self, msg):
    print (msg)
```

When I write the lines

```
gotAny = Spam(2)
gotAny.printMsg("We are the knights who say ni")
```

in each member function an implicit `self` argument is passed as the instance that actually called the function, so the way the caller is known by the method is clear enough.

**In C++ now**, we never put that extra `self` argument in method definitions, which troubles me in two ways :

- How is the caller known ?
- There is a `this` pointer but it only makes things more mysterious. The `this` pointer is neither a class member nor passed as an argument, so how does `this` exist inside member function definitions to begin with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed an object's `this` pointer is not part of the object itself. So in `sizeof(Spam)`, the size of `this` is not added to the size of the class.

What actually happens is very similar to Python's way of dealing with it (or IMHO better as it hides away this implementation details). When a nonstatic member function is called for an object, **the address of the object is passed by the compiler as a hidden argument** to the function.

So in your example

```
gotAny.printMsg("We are the knights who say ni");
```

can be read this way:

```
// corrected version by juanchopanza
Spam::printMsg(&gotAny, "We are the knights who say ni");
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dddwwd.aspx)

Comment: I find thinking of it as `Spam::printMsg(&gotAny, "We are the knights who say ni");` clearer. Then you can think of the `.` operator as syntactic sugar for the above (as in python.)

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, you are correct. The source I'm refering to, also mentions it this way (you can either edit the answer or I edit it and mention your correction - I'd prefer the 1st)